# what to put in the ActionImage[] part of OpenGraph?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'd like to integrate an application where users post photos on my site and relate that photo to this particular group that they were invited on.

I'm looking at this Opengraph console from Facebook and it says ActionImage[]. Do I link an actual sample of a photo from my site here or do i just write a mock url of the photo?

Answer (score 0):

in your params do image[0][user_generated]=true&image[0][url]=imageurl for example...